# Error #2130 Unable to flush sharedObject

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-media-server

I cant flush the shared object in my project. What can I do for that problem?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that the URL is valid. I had the same problem with a double slash (`//`) in the URL:

```
http://localhost/myProject//MyProject.html?debug=true
```

Comment: Hey, today I ran into this problem again and funnily enough I was answering this to myself! :-D

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm glad I found your answer and saved myself spending time in fixing this hard to find bug.

Answer (score 1):

Flash should be allowed to store data to your hard drive. You can configure storage settings here :

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager03.html

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem in Windows 7. I went to control panel and allowed storage from there. you can do the same at

```
Control Panel -> System & Security -> Flash Player
```

Answer (score -2):

"Error #2130 Unable to flush sharedObject" can also happen when you do flash() on remote object with debug(!) version of Flash player installed.
[Uninstall](http://helpx.adobe.com/flex/kb/uninstalling-flash-player-debugger.html) debug version and install a normal one to solve the problem.